# Cant find interface in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, interface, postman, postman-collection-runner

My server starts up fine but when I use postman to send a request I get a 404 not found. In my server details on console it says "Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 4 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces." I'm just trying to get a simple check to see if a employee is in my MySQL database.

My repository

```
package com.kingMachine.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.kingMachine.entity.Employees;

@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employees, String>{

    @Query("Select S from Employees S where S.id = ?1 and S.password = ?2")
    Employees login(String id, String password);
}
```

My Controller

```
package com.kingMachine.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.kingMachine.entity.Employees;
import com.kingMachine.repository.EmployeeRepository;

public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    
    //login info finds user by id and password in a query
    @RequestMapping(value="/login",
            produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            method=RequestMethod.POST
            )
    public ResponseEntity<Employees>login(@RequestBody Employees employees){
        Employees employeeLogin = employeeRepository.login(employees.getId(), employees.getPassword());
        if(employeeLogin != null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(employeeLogin, HttpStatus.OK);
        }else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }
}
```

Main Application

```
package com.kingMachine.login;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.kingMachine")
public class LoginApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LoginApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Finally POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.kingMachine</groupId>
    <artifactId>login</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>login</name>
    <description>KingMachine Login</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.2.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Try putting @RestController on your controller. Issues with the repository should result in other errors.

Answer (score 0):

Specify LoginApplication annotations

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.kingMachine")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.kingMachine.repository")
@EntityScan("com.kingMachine.entity")
public class LoginApplication {
```

and add @Controller annotation to EmployeeController so it can be scanned

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your main class is not in parent package of your repositories. You need to use `@EnableJpaRepositories`. Or just move you main class into `com.kingMachine`